# PHP regex to find version (dotted decimal) if exists in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Using PHP, I need to extract a version string (dotted decimal) if it exists in a given string, returning both parts.

Consider:

"Foobar R2" should return 'Foobar R2' and ''

"Foobar R2 12.23" should return 'Foobar R2' and '12.23'

"12.2.3.4.5.5" should return '' and '12.2.3.4.5.5'

There are many answers to the problem of just finding the version, but I require both parts of the string.

Thanks as always.

Comment: What regex have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match('/^(.*?)\s*\b((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?)$/', $input, $match);
```

Comment: This pattern fails with the following input:

Foobar R11 1.2.3.4

Comment: I would expect "Foobar R11" and "1.2.3.4".

Comment: @alindber: remove the `\s*`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use one of the many answers that find the version using `preg_match` and supply the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag.

This way you will get back the offset of the match in the source string in addition to its length, so it will then be trivial to break down the input string with e.g. `substr` appropriately.

Another option would be to simply `str_replace` the version with the empty string, which leaves you with the "everything else" part.

Comment: I took your advice and resolved my issue with the following code:
$pattern = "/[\d.]+\.\d+/";

Comment: $pattern = "/[\d.]+\.\d+/";  preg_match("$pattern",$t,$results,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if(sizeof($results) > 0) {
 $Variant = trim(substr($t,0,$results[0][1]));
 $Version = $results[0][0];
} else {
 $Variant = $t;
 $Version = "";
}